# Spring cannot deserialize the request body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

When I access the contents of  GenericMockingForm its null

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**", produces = "application/json")
    public class GenericMockingController {

        @Autowired private GenericMockingService genericMockingService;

        @ResponseBody
        @PostMapping
        public ResponseEntity<String> processRequest(@RequestBody GenericMockingForm genericMockingForm, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
            String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(genericMockingService.getJsonResponse(genericMockingForm, requestURI), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    public class GenericMockingForm {

        private List<String> productIds;
        private String salesChannelId;
        private Locale locale;

        public List<String> getProductIds() {
            return productIds;
        }

        public void setProductIds(List<String> productIds) {
            this.productIds = productIds;
        }

        public String getSalesChannelId() {
            return salesChannelId;
        }

        public void setSalesChannelId(String salesChannelId) {
            this.salesChannelId = salesChannelId;
        }

        public Locale getLocale() {
            return locale;
        }

        public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
            this.locale = locale;
        }
    }

    test payload and ulr http://localhost:8088/product/get-products:

    {
        "product_ids": ["1420-15595-82", "1420-58134-82"],
        "sales_channel_id": "www-k24-at",
        "locale": "de_DE"
    }
```

Above is my code

How to deserialize the request payload?
When I access the contents of  GenericMockingForm its null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kfz24.mockingservice.service.impl.GernericMockingServiceImpl.getJsonResponse(GernericMockingServiceImpl.java:32)
    at com.kfz24.mockingservice.controller.GenericMockingController.processRequest(GenericMockingController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test payload should be:

```
{
    "productIds": ["1420-15595-82", "1420-58134-82"],
    "salesChannelId": "www-k24-at",
    "locale": "de_DE"
}
```

Comment: Ohh!! ya. But I cannot modify payload and it is from the other service . i have to change my POJO structure

Answer (score 1):

Ok.I fixed the issue by changing the structure of the POJO

```
public class GenericMockingForm {

    @JsonProperty("product_ids")
    private List<String> productIds;
    @JsonProperty("sales_channel_id")
    private String salesChannelId;
    @JsonProperty("locale")
    private Locale locale;

    public List<String> getProductIds() {
        return productIds;
    }

    public void setProductIds(List<String> productIds) {
        this.productIds = productIds;
    }

    public String getSalesChannelId() {
        return salesChannelId;
    }

    public void setSalesChannelId(String salesChannelId) {
        this.salesChannelId = salesChannelId;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
}
```